# Accuracy warnings in scipy.special

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

I am running an MCMC sampler which requires the calculation of the hypergeometric function at each step using `scipy.special.hyp2f1()`.

At certain points on my grid (which I do not care about) the solutions to the hypergeometric function are quite unstable and SciPy prints the warning:

```
Warning! You should check the accuracy
```

This is rather annoying, and over 1000s of samples may well slow down my routine.

I have tried using `special.errprint(0)` with no luck, as well as disabling all warnings in Python using both the `warnings` module and the `-W ignore` flag.

The offending function (called from another file) is below

```
from numpy import pi, hypot, real, imag
import scipy.special as special

def deflection_angle(p, (x1, x2)):

    # Find the normalisation constant
    norm = (p.f * p.m * (p.r0 ** (t - 2.0)) / pi) ** (1.0 / t)

    # Define the complex plane
    z = x1 + 1j * x2

    # Define the radial coordinates
    r = hypot(x1, x2)

    # Truncate the radial coordinates
    r_ = r * (r < p.r0).astype('float') + p.r0 * (r >= p.r0).astype('float')

    # Calculate the radial part
    radial = (norm ** 2 / (p.f * z)) * ((norm / r_) ** (t - 2))

    # Calculate the angular part
    h1, h2, h3 = 0.5, 1.0 - t / 2.0, 2.0 - t / 2.0
    h4 = ((1 - p.f ** 2) / p.f ** 2) * (r_ / z) ** 2
    special.errprint(0)
    angular = special.hyp2f1(h1, h2, h3, h4)

    # Assemble the deflection angle
    alpha = (- radial * angular).conjugate()

    # Separate real and imaginary parts
    return real(alpha), imag(alpha)`
```

Comment: Here's an easy way to reproduce the warning: `hyp2f1(1/2., 2/3., 3/2., .75j + .09j)`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, hyp2f1 is notoriously hard to compute over some non-trivial areas of the parameter space. Many implementations would dilently produce inaccurate or wildly wrong results. Scipy.special tries hard to at least monitor convergence. An alternative could be to usr arbitrary precision implementations, e.g. mpmath. But these would certainly be quite a bit slower, so MCMC users beware.

EDIT: Ok, this seems to be scipy version dependent. I tried @wrwrwr's example on scipy 0.13.3, and it reproduces what you see: "Warning! You should check the accuracy" is printed regardless of the `errprint` status. However, doing the same with the dev version, I get

```
In [12]: errprint(True)
Out[12]: 0

In [13]: hyp2f1(0.5, 2/3., 1.5, 0.09j+0.75j)
/home/br/virtualenvs/scipy_py27/bin/ipython:1: SpecialFunctionWarning: scipy.special/chyp2f1: loss of precision
  #!/home/br/virtualenvs/scipy_py27/bin/python
Out[13]: (0.93934867949609357+0.15593972567482395j)

In [14]: errprint(False)
Out[14]: 1

In [15]: hyp2f1(0.5, 2/3., 1.5, 0.09j+0.75j)
Out[15]: (0.93934867949609357+0.15593972567482395j)
```

So, apparently it got fixed at some point between 2013 and now. You might want to upgrade your scipy version.

Comment: I originally used mpmath but as you say it was too slow. I have checked the accuracy and the areas on the complex plane where the solution blows up are not important to my results.The problem here isn't the accuracy at all - it's that scipy will not stop telling me about it!